# How to disable automated E-Mail on PHP error/exception?

Tags: email, customization, fatal-error, errors

Since WordPress 5.2 there is an automated E-Mail on PHP exceptions. In some smaller projects I just upload the files for new extensions while developing - whenever an error occurs then, the site admin is getting an email. This is usually one of my freelance customers and they unecessarily panic then.

Therefore I would like to turn of this email notifications (without changing the admin email). Is there some kind of action/filter, config option (e.g. define) to disable this behaviour? Some true/false option would be the best? Then I can disable this just for the times I develop.

Comment: Do you only want to disable the email notification? If not, setting `WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER` should deactivate the whole thing

Comment: @kero It would be better to only disable the email notification. I do  not know exactly what the error handler does, therefore I am not sure if it is a good idea to disable it completely.

Comment: Well with 
 define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
 define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
 define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
 define('WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER',true);
you can still see and log the errors, but not mail them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was some discussion on it a few weeks ago you can find here:
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/04/16/fatal-error-recovery-mode-in-5-2/

According to that and [looking through the core](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-recovery-mode-email-service.php#L213), you can accomplish that with one of two methods:

```
define('RECOVERY_MODE_EMAIL', 'foo@bar.com');
```

OR

```
add_filter( 'recovery_mode_email', 'recovery_email_update', 10, 2 );
  function recovery_email_update( $email, $url ) {
    $email['to'] = 'foo@bar.com';
    return $email;
 }
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Is the aim of this to change the email? How is it connected with disabling? Do you mean to set it to a non-existent email?

Answer (score 7):

I have thoroughly tested the above suggestions and neither of them work.

The only thing I have found that DOES work is adding the following to "wp-config.php":

`define('WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER',true);`

Comment: Worked perfectly

Comment: What does this do besides disabling the e-mail?

Comment: @JānisElmeris
As most of the defines in Wordpress it seems do only this one thing:
The only place where it gets checked is in wp_is_fatal_error_handler_enabled.
see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_fatal_error_handler_enabled/

Comment: OK, thanks! You wouldn't tell by the name though. It may potentially do something else in the future, as it's a "fatal error handler", but I would like to disable the e-mailing only.